# Jquerymobile Alter Tab bar Navbar IText

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm building an app with JQuerymobile and using a tab bar.

In my app I want to change one of the tab bar labels (and icons)

I added a class to the tab bar list item `a` tag and try to do this:

```
$(".nav_login_button").val("Test")
```

but it doesn't change it because JQuerymobile's javascript manipulated the DOM a bunch. I could do it manually by checking how things changed, but not only is this messy, a different structure occurs for the "active" tab bar page vs the hidden tab bars.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround.

Instead of making a class on the anchor , I made a class on the actual value.

```
<a  href="#login" data-transition="fade" data-theme="f" data-icon="delete">
Login
</a>
```

to

```
<a  href="#login" data-transition="fade" data-theme="f" data-icon="delete">
<span class="nav_login_button">Login</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Anchor</span></span>
```

jQuery mobile adds the above markup for buttons. So to change the text of button you have to use following:

```
$("#buttonId .ui-btn-text").text("New text");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/androdify/FQyUd/

Answer (score 0):

Check demo here http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/ttjGv/4/

```
$("#change").on('click', function () {
    $("#myTab li .ui-btn-text").text("New text");
});
```